# magento2.2.4 error while extracting winRAR file

Tags: magento2, configuration, magento2.2.4

> !
>   C:\Users\dell\Downloads\Magento-CE-2.2.4_sample_data-2018-05-01-09-51-36.tar.gz:
>   Cannot create
>   vendor\magento\magento2-base\dev\tests\integration\testsuite\Magento\Framework\View_files\fallback\design\frontend\Vendor\custom_theme\ViewTest_Module\templates\fixture_template_two.phtml
>   !
>   C:\Users\dell\Downloads\Magento-CE-2.2.4_sample_data-2018-05-01-09-51-36.tar.gz:
>   Cannot create
>   vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Service\WindowsAzure\CommandLine\Scaffolders\DefaultScaffolder\resources\PhpOnAzure.Web\resources\WebPICmdLine\Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.UI.dll
>   !
>   C:\Users\dell\Downloads\Magento-CE-2.2.4_sample_data-2018-05-01-09-51-36.tar.gz:
>   Cannot create
>   vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Service\WindowsAzure\CommandLine\Scaffolders\DefaultScaffolder\resources\PhpOnAzure.Web\resources\WebPICmdLine\Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.dll

[image]

Comment: Download Magento 2.2.4 without sample data and install. After that you can install the sample data through command line.